# Backbone view based on model from collection, how to update view?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am looking for a bit of direction I am still fairly new to Backbone and am currently creating a test application to learn more.

My problem is this, I am populating a backbone view with a underscore template. I load a collection of models, then I find the model I need and populate these values into the template. There can be many pages based on the template so I have a dynamic route that accepts an id.

My problem is I want to add a next feature, that would change the current page and reload the template with the new model.

I have tried a crude method along the lines of :

```
Backbone.history.navigate(newLocation)
```

However this did'nt work, please note newLocation is actually populated with the route and the id I want to navigate to.

I will add some code from my view below, I won't include the full code however if it is needed please ask.

Any help or a push in the right direction would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your router object's `navigate` method rather than than `history`'s class method, and you need to pass it the option `{trigger: true} in order to invoke the corresponding route function.

Comment: ah brilliant, I will give it a whirl and let you know how I get on. Many thanks

Comment: thanks that worked ill mark your answer as correct. One thing I have noticed is that if I don't add the # it does'nt work. but in my url i end up with 2 #'s have u noticed this. eg. ##route/2

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question (in which you show your routes and an example of a `navigate` call).